# How to remove old/closed tasks in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I have the following task menu in IntelliJ. What I want is to clear it completly. I don't care if I have to remove a settings folder or something like that. But I want it to be cleared. Deleting every single task is not an option because there are hundreds of then.
I figured out it has to be something in the .idea folder or in the settings because I already freshly installed IntelliJ

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can select many tasks with <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then delete all of them at once, which is much faster than removing all the tasks individually:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-tasks-and-context.html#delete-tasks

Alternatively, all tasks are stored in `workspace.xml`in .idea folder under `<component name="TaskManager">`, such as:

```
<task active="true" id="LOCAL-00674" summary="Some Task">
      <created>1501071813825</created>
      <option name="number" value="00674" />
      <option name="presentableId" value="LOCAL-00674" />
      <option name="project" value="LOCAL" />
      <updated>1501071815536</updated>
      <workItem from="1501071815699" duration="59000" />
</task>
```

You can delete them all from there.

Comment: thanks but these are hundreds of tasks which I just dont want to remove manually

Comment: Updated my answer.